# DAB+ (Digital audio broadcasting) privacy

Tags: privacy

Soon FM radio will be switched-off in Europe. I wish to buy a DAB+ device and read in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_audio_broadcasting) about it.

I really don't understand what consumer privacy DAB+ offers me. Does the radio channel know that I am listening at 20:00 the program XY? Does it depend on the device I will buy? What's a good choice if I wish best privacy in radio?

Comment: Pretty sure that DAB+ doesn't have any two-way capability inherently - while there may be devices which report back via other means (e.g. over wifi), it's fundamentally a broadcast system. Big broadcast aerial somewhere, lots of little receive-only aerials pick up signal and turn it back into sound.

Comment: Your first sentence is a bit misleading, since there is no Europe-wide rollout of digital radio or switch-off of analogue. For instance, although the government has stated an intention to do so, no date has yet been announced for switching off FM in the UK; and according to Wikipedia, Portugal abandoned DAB in 2011.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DAB+ is a one-way signal transmission. A big, high-powered sender sends data encoded according to the standard, and the small, low-powered receiver receives the data, decodes it and plays the audio stream back.

## Does that mean my radio is 100% private?

Most likely, yes. The DAB+ standard describes no signal sent from the radio and received by the base station.

This does not mean that there could not be a "smart radio" that transmits somewhere what you are listening to. It just means that it's not part of the standard.

So if you wish to remain as private as possible with your choice of radio station, don't buy a "smart" radio.